# Chrome versus Firefox - which is better?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Perhaps this is not the best title to use, but I'm running 12.04, which I always update. I'm not sure if it is just my impression, but is Chrome really buggy? I generally use the latest updated version. That's my browser of choice, but it seems to drain my resources and I resorted to Firefox instead.

Any information/comments?

Comment: This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum. I would recommend using the ubuntu forums for this. There you can even access tools like polls to see if others see similar issues as yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of question more applicable to fora - you'll be getting a lot of radical posts :)
Anyway, I find Chrome slightly buggy, and in general that Firefox works much better than Chrome on Ubuntu, even speed-wise. And it is completely open-source, updates very often (next three versions all coming this year with loads of new features), and has all the add-ons you could possibly need. I myself was a Chrome-fan till a few months back, and, well, I'm not turning back. If you like Chrome's looks (like me), you can get all of them by using the right themes (Chrome-FX) and add-ons. You can even get downloads to open in a new tab, put downloads in the status bar, anything. It is also much more customizable, even if you don't use the about:config page.

One more thing I notice is that, on Ubuntu (but not Windows), having many add-ons slows Chrome down, but not Firefox.